# How can I downgrade a module with Composer?

Tags: 8, composer

I updated the following module to its stable version :

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist/releases/8.x-2.0-rc2

This module completely broke my site. There has been no database update. How can I revert to the RC2 version ?

Comment: `composer require 'drupal/commerce_pricelist:2.0-rc2'` doesn't work?

Comment: How about simply uninstalling it and installing again older version?

Comment: The problem is not about uninstalling the module, because the OP said there is no database update which needs to be removed. If this were the case then it might be a better idea to restore a database backup so that you don't lose any module data. So this is only about managing the code base via composer. The OP probably did `composer require` with `^` or `~` allowing automatic updates within a version range. To downgrade then to a specific version you can simply run this command again, now with a specific version without range operator, see my first comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Open your `composer.json` and search for the line containing `drupal/commerce_pricelist`
- Replace the line by this one : `"drupal/commerce_pricelist": "2.0-rc2",`
- Execute `composer update drupal/commerce_pricelist`

Or simply run `composer require 'drupal/commerce_pricelist:2.0-rc2'` as suggested @4k4 in the comments

Comment: You do not remove `composer.lock` as that will lose track of all the other installed module versions.

Comment: Yeah, instead of removing your lock file, do `composer install && composer update --lock`. Also important to maybe uninstall the module before that and then reinstall it after downgrading as the newer version may have triggered some update hooks.

Comment: (Mac, maybe fix the answer so people can upvote it again.)

Comment: Done, I edited with your command @leymannx

Comment: Still not quite right - this will also potentially install updates to other packages. In order to downgrade a single package as in the OP, just do `composer update drupal/commerce_pricelist` after changing the version number. Or just the command 4k4 put in their original comment, that’ll do the same thing

Comment: Are we good now ?

Comment: Yep all good, sorry for the pile-on :)

Comment: @Clive – The `--lock` flag is to tell Composer to only update the lock file, and to not download or update any dependency. From the manual: `--lock Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date`. Though the other suggestions are fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is an example of why you should [use version control](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/linux-development-environments/set-up-a-local-development-drupal-0-5).  If you are using a version control system such as Git, you will not have to use `composer` itself to downgrade.

If you are using git, and you commit `composer.lock` and `composer.json` each time you update your modules with composer, then all you have to do is `git revert` the previous commit (or `git checkout` if you haven't committed the changes yet) and then run `composer install`.

Comment: I disagree since you wouldn't commit something which completely break the site

Comment: @MacSim Well, someone might make a commit by mistake.  And if you don't make a mistake with your commit, it's even easier; you can use `git checkout` as I already stated in my answer.

Comment: With `git checkout` you'll see the diff in the `composer.lock` and `composer.json` but you won't revert the changes made in the /vendor directory when you upgraded your component unless you commit your vendor directory too - I don't.

Comment: @MacSim ...Which is why I said to run `composer install` after running `git checkout`.  Maybe you prefer a different way, but this method does work.

Comment: My bad, my mind thought we were speaking about `git diff` xD yeah if you make a new feature branch with `git checkout` it works but you don't need to `git revert` then, simply checkout to the previous branch and delete the broken branch.

Comment: But still, I personnaly put my contrib modules in `/web/modules/contrib` and this path is in my `.gitignore` (I commit my `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and run `composer install` on each env). That means that if I checkout to another branch the changes made locally in this directory are not reverted.