# Composer downgrading module version

Tags: composer, version-control

I wish to move the bootstrap theme from the repository
located in the folder `theme/custom` to be a dependency in `composer.json`

I've checked that the current version `drupal/bootstrap` is `3.16`

I perform `rm -rf web/theme/custom/bootstrap`
`composer require drupal/bootstrap:8.x-3.16`
^^-> wrong syntax and have decided to just `composer require drupal/bootstrap`

Now I need to downgrade the version of drupal/bootstrap in composer.json
and perform `composer update --lock`

But I got an error:

```
Nothing to modify in lock file
Unable to find a compatible set of packages based on your non-dev requirements alone.
Your requirements can be resolved successfully when require-dev packages are present.
You may need to move packages from require-dev or some of their dependencies to require.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/bootstrap 3.16, found drupal/bootstrap[3.23.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Any hints would appreciate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I downgrade a module with Composer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297861/how-can-i-downgrade-a-module-with-composer)

Answer (score 0):

What that I have done to fix it is obvious from the question
remove drupal/bootstrap from composer.lock and from composer.json
`composer require drupal/bootstrap:3.16`